# replace amount in file and save it to file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make changes in text file and then save them to the file. For example if we have text file that contains this information:

> user1;2000

> user2;3000

and I want to change 2000 to 1800 and save it to the file. How can I do that?
This is what i have so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("names.txt", std::fstream::in);
    std::vector<std::string>data;//to store all lines
    std::vector<double>balance;//to store amounts

    if(file.is_open()) {
        std::string line;

        while(getline(file, line)) {
            data.push_back(line);
            int find;
            find = line.find(';');
            std::string amountString = line.substr(find+1, line.size());
            double amount = stod(amountString);
            balance.push_back(amount);
        }
    }

    file.close();

    balance[0] -= 200;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a new user here, please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, what is the problem? How far are you? What is the next step you're having problems with? Also, it sometimes helps to investigate one part of the problem in isolation, like e.g. reading and writing.

Comment: If you want to read and write to the same file, you might want to consider using `std::fstream` instead of `std::ifstream` and remove the second parameter from `file.open`, so that it defaults to `ios_base::in|ios_base::out`. However, this could get complicated if the old text is not the same length as the replacement text, so you might want to keep the input and output file separate and use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Okay but how can i change the amount in the file?

Comment: I am preparing an answer, please wait

Comment: Since you are not changing the length of the file, it would probably be sufficient to use `std::fstream` instead of `std::ifstream` and remove the second parameter from `file.open`, as described above. However, I think it would probably still be easier to program if you had separate input and output files, because working with file offsets in text mode can be tricky and inefficient. Therefore, I suggest you read the input file line by line and write those lines to the output file, changing the lines as needed.

Comment: Of course, there is nothing wrong with your approach of storing all lines in a `std::vector` of `std::string`. That will just take more memory than handling one line at a time, but you can do it that way, too, if you want. After reading in all the input, you can then do all the changes you want, and then write them to the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already drafted a good 1st version.

Now, your next question is, how to save the modified data. This is not that easy with text files. Basically it is only hardly possible under special circumstances. If you do not use databases, where the data can be stored record by record, then one recommended approach would be:

- Read all data in memory (you did that already)
- Modify the data (alsothis you did already)
- Save the data in your file by overwriting the existent file (so, after your file close statement). Here, you have 2 possibilities
- a.) Simply open your file again, this time for output, and then overrite it by simply outputting the new data.
- b.) Open a temp file, write the modfied data to the temp file (you know, if that worked or not), then delete the original file and rename the tempfile to the original file name

Option b.) is a little bit safer.

Let me give to you a general example (unrelated to your problem) on how to do that:

Option a.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> readFile(const std::string& filename) {

    // Here we will store all the data from the file
    std::vector<std::string> fileData;

    // Open the source file
    std::ifstream fileStream(filename);

    // Read line by line and add it to our fileData
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(fileStream, line)) {

        fileData.push_back(line);
    }
    return fileData;
}

void writeFile(std::vector<std::string>& fileData, const std::string& filename) {

    // Open file for output
    std::ofstream fileStream(filename);

    // Write all data to file
    for (const std::string& line : fileData)
        fileStream << line << '\n';
}

int main() {

    // Aproach with read complete file to local variable, modify and the store again
    const std::string dataFileName("r:\\test.txt");

    // Get file content
    std::vector<std::string> data = readFile(dataFileName);


    // Now go through all records and do something
    for (std::string& line : data) {

        // If some condition is met then do something, for example modify
        if (line == "Line1") line += " modified";
    }


    // And then write the new data to the file
    writeFile(data, dataFileName);

    return 0;
}
```

---

And for option b.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    // Aproach with temp file, remove and rename, and on the fly change

    const std::string dataFileName("r:\\test.txt");
    const std::string tempFileName("r:\\temp.txt");
    bool writingtoTempFileWasOK = true;


    {
        // Open the source file with data
        std::ifstream dataFileStream(dataFileName);

        // Open the temporary file for output
        std::ofstream tempFileStream(tempFileName);

        // Now read the source file line by line with a simple for loop
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(dataFileStream, line) && writingtoTempFileWasOK) {

            // Identify the line that should be deleted and do NOT write it to the temp file
            if (line != "SearchString") {  // Or any other condition

                // Write only, if the condition is not met
                if (not (tempFileStream << line << '\n'))
                    writingtoTempFileWasOK = false;
            }
        }
    } // The end of the scope for the streams, will call their destructor and close the files


    // Now, remove and rename
    if (writingtoTempFileWasOK) {
        std::remove(dataFileName.c_str());
        std::rename(tempFileName.c_str(), dataFileName.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, after your line `balance[0] -= 200;`, you could then reopen the file and store again all data by writing (using option .a) something like

```
    if (std::ofstream ofs("names.txt"); ofs) {
        for (size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
            ofs << . . . // Whatever you want
    }
```

---

But, I would not do this at all.

In my opinion you should refactor your design.

At the moment you are using 2 different `std::vector` to store data, that belong togehter. That may lead to problems with synchronizing both `std::vectors`. And, you are missing the information about transactions (Modification of the amount).

In C++, we normally group the info in a struct, and then write methords, to work on such info.

I will show you a C++ solution, using modern C++17 elements, on how such an object oriented approach could be done. This is maybe to advanced, but you could get an idea for your own design and implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

struct Balance {

    // The data that we want to use
    std::string user{};
    double amount{};

    // Extractor operator. Extract data from a stream (Read the values)
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Balance& b) {

        // Read a complete line and check, if that worked
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) 

            if (line.empty()) {
                is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            }
            else
            {

                // Pack the line in a std::istringstream in order to be able to extract the user name from a string
                if (std::istringstream iss{ line }; std::getline(iss, b.user, ';'))
                    // If reading of user name worked then read amount
                    iss >> b.amount;
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Inserter operator. Write data to an ostream. (Save data values)
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Balance& b) {
        return os << b.user << ';' << b.amount;
    }
};

int main() {

    const std::string sourceFileName{ "r:\\names.txt" };
    const std::string tempFileName{ "r:\\temp.txt" };

    // Here we will store all our data
    std::vector<Balance> balance{};

    bool everythingOk{ false };
    // Open temp file name, and check, if that worked
    if (std::ofstream tempFileStream(tempFileName); tempFileStream) {

        // Open source file with names and amounts and check if that worked
        if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream(sourceFileName); sourceFileStream) {

            // Read/copy the complete source file and assign our internal data values
            std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Balance>(sourceFileStream), {}, std::back_inserter(balance));

            // For debug purposes, show result on screen
            std::copy(balance.begin(), balance.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Balance>(std::cout, "\n"));

            // Modifiy some value
            balance[0].amount -= 200;

            // Write everything to tempfile
            std::copy(balance.begin(), balance.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Balance>(tempFileStream, "\n"));

            everythingOk = tempFileStream.good() ;

        } // End of scope for if. Destructor for sourceFileStream will be called. This will close the source file
        else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open source file '" << sourceFileName << "'\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open temp file '" << tempFileName << "'\n\n";

    if (everythingOk) {
        std::remove(sourceFileName.c_str());
        std::rename(tempFileName.c_str(), sourceFileName.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, you also tried to spilt a string separated by a ';'

Splitting a string into tokens is a very old task. There are many many solutions available. All have different properties. Some are difficult to understand, some are hard to develop, some are more complex, slower or faster or more flexible or not.

Alternatives

1. Handcrafted, many variants, using pointers or iterators,  maybe hard to develop and error prone.
2. Using old style `std::strtok` function. Maybe unsafe. Maybe should not be used any longer
3. `std::getline`. Most used implementation. But actually a "misuse" and not so flexible
4. Using dedicated modern function, specifically developed for this purpose, most flexible and good fitting into the STL environment and algortithm landscape. But slower.

Please see 4 examples in one piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
#include <forward_list>
#include <deque>

using Container = std::vector<std::string>;
std::regex delimiter{ "," };


int main() {

    // Some function to print the contents of an STL container
    auto print = [](const auto& container) -> void { std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::decay<decltype(*container.begin())>::type>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; };

    // Example 1:   Handcrafted -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Search for comma, then take the part and add to the result
        for (size_t i{ 0U }, startpos{ 0U }; i <= stringToSplit.size(); ++i) {

            // So, if there is a comma or the end of the string
            if ((stringToSplit[i] == ',') || (i == (stringToSplit.size()))) {

                // Copy substring
                c.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(startpos, i - startpos));
                startpos = i + 1;
            }
        }
        print(c);
    }

    // Example 2:   Using very old strtok function ----------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Split string into parts in a simple for loop
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
        for (char* token = std::strtok(const_cast<char*>(stringToSplit.data()), ","); token != nullptr; token = std::strtok(nullptr, ",")) {
            c.push_back(token);
        }

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 3:   Very often used std::getline with additional istringstream ------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Put string in an std::istringstream
        std::istringstream iss{ stringToSplit };

        // Extract string parts in simple for loop
        for (std::string part{}; std::getline(iss, part, ','); c.push_back(part))
            ;

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 4:   Most flexible iterator solution  ------------------------------------------------

    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };


        Container c(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
        //
        // Everything done already with range constructor. No additional code needed.
        //

        print(c);


        // Works also with other containers in the same way
        std::forward_list<std::string> c2(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});

        print(c2);

        // And works with algorithms
        std::deque<std::string> c3{};
        std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(c3));

        print(c3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```